# CSS- Making LIST

Tags: html, css, html-lists

how can i do somehing like thhs:
[image]

I try things like this:

```
    <div class="servers">
      <ul>
          <li><span class="icon"></li>   
          <li><span class="text">Public server#1</span></li>
          <li>IP: 88.88.88.87:270115</li>
          <li><MAPA: de_dust2/li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
```

Also try things like:

```
<li><span class="icon"></span><span class="text"> Public server#1</span></li><li><span class="text">IP:81.0.217.184:27020</span></li><li><span class="text">Mapa: de_dust2</span></li<span class="text">Hráči: 50/60</span></li>
```

with CSS:

```
.text {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 170px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

I know its stupid question but i am just lost i need to make same spaces betwween tihngs, and just dont know how to do it simply :)

If there is someone who can help me i will be really thanksfull

Comment: Considering you are displaying tabular data, you might want to consider using an actual table rather than an ordered list.  The setup for your list is wrong anyway.  You would define the "icon" as the bullet type in your CSS, for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Table would be the best approach here. **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9VFU4/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="icon"></span>Public Server#1</td>
        <td>IP:87.45.26.27:27015</td>
        <td>Mapa:de_dust2</td>
        <td>Hraci: 16/32</td>
        <td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.icon {
    background: url(img.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the times a table is actually applicable.

Try styling this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="icon"></td>
      <td>Public server#1</td>
      <td>IP: 88.88.88.87:270115</td>
      <td>MAPA: de_dust2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="icon"></td>
      <td>Public server#1</td>
      <td>IP: 88.88.88.87:270115</td>
      <td>MAPA: de_dust2</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
<div id="servers">
     <div class="server">
         <div class="icon"><img src="icon.png" /></div>
         <div class="name">Server #1</div>
         <div class="ip">88.88.88.88:27000</div>
         <div class="map">office</div>
     </div>
     <div class="server">
         <div class="icon"><img src="icon.png" /></div>
         <div class="name">Server #2</div>
         <div class="ip">88.88.88.88:27000</div>
         <div class="map">dust</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

here's a fiddle with style http://jsfiddle.net/r84Du/

Answer (score 0):

A table looks like a good way to go, here is a fiddle with a little CSS.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Public Server #1</td><td>IP: 88.87.65.43:27015</td><td>Mapa: de_dust2</td><td>Hraci: 16/32</td><td><a href="#">Detaily</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sm8Y2/